# Keras LSTM constant loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have an issue where the loss of my LSTM network does not change at all from one epoch to another.

**It does not happen systematically.** Given the same code and the same dataset, one execution can run fine and the loss can decrease with each epoch, while another execution can run into the constant loss issue. I cannot determine what makes it go one way or another, it seems random.

**Why do the same code and dataset lead to two different outcomes ?**

Model code :

```
mdl = Sequential()
mdl.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(1, lags), activation='relu'))
mdl.add(LSTM(6, activation='relu'))
mdl.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
mdl.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
mdl.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, verbose=2)
```

Execution #1 (success) :

```
Epoch 1/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.0401
Epoch 2/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0091
Epoch 3/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0025
Epoch 4/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0012
Epoch 5/10
 - 0s - loss: 8.3705e-04
Epoch 6/10
 - 0s - loss: 6.6625e-04
Epoch 7/10
 - 0s - loss: 5.7399e-04
Epoch 8/10
 - 0s - loss: 5.4451e-04
Epoch 9/10
 - 0s - loss: 5.0578e-04
Epoch 10/10
 - 0s - loss: 4.7520e-04
```

Execution #2 (constant loss) :

```
Epoch 1/10
 - 1s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 2/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 3/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 4/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 5/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 6/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 7/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 8/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 9/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
Epoch 10/10
 - 0s - loss: 0.0884
```

Comment: it may stuck in local min. you can fix the random seed to fix outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? Because of random initialization of the neural network weights. This defines the starting point in weight space, and it seems in your case, some starting points are really bad.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. So to avoid this situation, should I initialize the weights with specific values ?

Comment: @JonathanHartnagel No, not really, there is no solution other than retraining if it gets stuck. Maybe changing learning rates could help, or using other optimizers, or different models, but in general its not something you can debug.

Comment: You should specify the seed which you are using for more reproducable results.

Comment: @VegardKT I suppose there's a good reason why randomness is used though. I guess one wouldn't use a fixed seed in production.